# Dart/sass on OSX 10.13.3 "Cannot open file"

Tags: macos, sass

In trying to learn/use sass for 1st time, I used Homebrew to install dart-sass on recently updated High Sierra  10.13.3   . That worked and sass --version shows 1.1.1    I created a simple .scss file:

```
$color: #d9534f;

body {
    color: $color;
}
```

and  while in the same directory, then issued:

```
sass main.scss main.css  --trace
```

in console and got:

```
Error reading main: Cannot open file.

dart:io                               _File.readAsBytesSync
package:sass/src/io/vm.dart 27        readFile
package:sass/src/compile.dart 33      compile
package:sass/sass.dart 63             compile
package:sass/src/executable.dart 110  main
```

What do I need to change, learn  or do to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Oops. Reinstall.    I ran

brew update      multiple times, then 
brew uninstall sass    then
brew install --devel sass/sass/sass

and now

sass main.scss main.css

works.